# how to search in kibana (lucene syntaxe) values containing "?"?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana

I am using ELK and I need to filter all the documents with an unmatched COUNTRY (from geoip)

Theses properties looks like:

'IPCOUNTRY': '??'

But I just can't filter on this special value...

I tried

- IPCOUNTRY:?? => ? is evaluated > returns all records > normal case-
- IPCOUNTRY:\?\? => Doesn't return any document... but lucene documentation says it should be the good way of achieving this...
- IPCOUNTRY:"??" => doesnt work
- IPCOUNTRY:'??' => doesnt work

EDIT:

This case doesn't work too
- IPCOUNTRY:/[^A-Z]{2}/

Simple but boring issue ^^

Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

You could try :

```
 !IPCOUNTRY:"?"
 -IPCOUNTRY:"?"
 NOT IPCOUNTRY:"?"
```

If you have an unanalyzed IPCOUNTRY field, you can do something like :

```
 !IPCOUNTRY.raw:"??"
```

Comment: Hmm, in fact those queries should return all documents with a good IPCOUNTRY field (NOT including "?").
Did you try the opposite? :
+IPCOUNTRY:"?"

Comment: Hmm, that's anormal.
+IPCOUNTRY:\?
+IPCOUNTRY:"\?"
If it does not work, I can't help you :/

Answer (score 0):

This is an elasticsearch mapping issue. Punctuation is dropped. You'll need to set your field to an analyzer that would keep ?. Maybe keyword? or not_analyzed?

extract from https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/6561#issuecomment-197951710

Answer (score 0):

If all of your fields have documents same as 'IPCOUNTRY': '??', then you can directly filter this field which will exclude the field from matches.

To directly add a filter you can do it in the following 2 ways:-

- In Discover page open the text and find the field. Click on + magnifier to add the field as a filter.
- In Discover page, on the left side where fields are listed. Click on field name & select the value portaying as ?? to add it as a filter.

Comment: What error are you getting?
Can you post more details to debug.

Comment: It returns no result. I think it is not a question of filter, but of analysed field

Comment: You can go to the settings, click on the index name and check whether the field is marked as analyzed or not.

Comment: Yes the field is analyzed, and I think this is the problem... I will try to reindex the data